# how to save the state of pagination in juery datatable?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable

I have datatable with user information.
I am getting information with saving data into database and fetching that data into datatable.
Every row has edit option where user info can be edited. My main concern is when I am editing the particular user from 2 or 3 page of datatable it goes to the 1st page after editing which i don't want(it should come back to the particular page).
and for creating new user I want to reload datatable and comes back to 1st page cause I am fetching the data in descending order.
so how to achieve this in datatable?

Comment: Listen for a change event when the user changes the page, call a PHP script via ajax which saves the page number to a session variable. When the page reloads, initiate the table and set it to the page in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the property "stateSave" does the job.
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html

Comment: stateSave does the job for edit option. but for creating new user (after submitting create user) it is not showing first page as it saves the current state of edit user(2nd or 3rd page)